# Let $A\in M_{5×5}(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix such that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$ and $A^3 = 0$. Is A guaranteed to be diagonalizable over R?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A\in M_{5×5}(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix such that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$ and $A^3 = 0$. Is A guaranteed to be diagonalizable over R?

I've been searching my notes for some sort of theorem that would help me with this problem, but I have had no luck.

Without the characteristic polynomial or actual eigenvalues, I can't seem to use the two step test for diagonalizability or any other theorem I know of for that matter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: From what you've supplied, what do you know about the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: $$A=\pmatrix{0&1&0&0&0\cr 0&0&1&0&0\cr 0&0&0&0&0\cr 0&0&0&0&0\cr0&0&0&0&0\cr}$$ has only a single eigenvalue $\lambda=0$, but not enough linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: No I do not know the eigenvalues, all known information is stated in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with minimal polynomials, then it is easy to see that the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$ and the system $(A-0I)v=0$ has only $3$ linearly independent solutions (eigenvectors) by virtue of $A$ having rank $2$. So $A$ is guaranteed to be non-diagonalizable.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense for the most part. Could you maybe elaborate as to why we know that the only possible eigenvalue is 0?

Comment: @complexanalysis The minimal polynomial of a matrix $A$ is a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $(1)~p(A)=0~~(2)$ if $q(x)$ is a polynomial that annihilates $A$ i.e. $q(A)=0$, then $p(x)$ divides $q(x)$ and $(3)$ the coefficient of largest degree term of $p(x)$ is $1$. The roots of the minimal polynomial give the distinct eigenvalues of $A$. Since $A^3=0$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^3$ whose only root is $0$. Learn more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)#:~:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20the%20minimal,polynomial)%20multiple%20of%20%CE%BCA.).

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ was diagonalizable, then $D^3=0,$ so $D=0,$ so $A=0,$ contradicting the fact that the rank is $2.$

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe explain the last part a little more?

Comment: @complexanalysis If $A = 0$, then $\mathrm{rank}(A) = 0$.